# Cannot initialize the state of ngrx (v. 4.x) store

Tags: ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

I am currently looking into using the ngrx store (v. 4.0.3) for state management. It seems like a great project.

I have hit a bit of a bump in the road while trying to initialize the state of my store. The [documentation](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/api.md#initial-state) makes it look rather simple, but yet I am not able to see where I am going wrong.

Here's the relevant code snippets:

in app.state.ts

```
export interface AppState {
    searchText: string;
}
```

In search-text.reducer.ts

```
export const UPDATE = 'UPDATE';

export class UpdateSearchTextAction implements Action {
    readonly type: string = UPDATE;
    constructor(public readonly text: string) {}
}

export function searchTextReducer(state: string, action: UpdateSearchTextAction) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case UPDATE:
        return action.text;
    }
};
```

In app.module.ts

```
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState, UpdateSearchTextAction> = {
    searchText: searchTextReducer
};

export const initialState: InitialState<AppState> = {
    searchText: 'sds'
};

....

imports: [
....
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, initialState)
]
```

in some Component

```
constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.searchBoxText = store.select('searchText');
    this.searchBoxText.subscribe(text => console.log('value = [' + text + "]"));
}
```

So, when the application loads, I would expect to see the following logged to the console:

```
value = [sds]
```

yet I see

```
value = [undefined]
```

Later, once I start typing in an input that triggers an UpdateSearchTextAction the console does indeed log the correct value. So it seems like I've setup the store correctly.

There is probably something real simple I'm missing. Can anyone provide some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are having it as `readonly` you are not allowed to assign the value,

```
export class UpdateSearchTextAction implements Action {
    readonly type: string = UPDATE;
    constructor(public text: string) {}
}
```

And you need to dispatch the value using a `dispatch` statement

```
this.store.dispatch(new UpdateSearchTextAction.UPDATE(<<string>>));
```

Comment: What you suggest is what I've already been doing, but only in response to user input. What I'm trying to figure out is how do I set the initial  state of the AppState without dispatching an Action. Since the signature of the StoreModule.forRoot, takes a reducer and a StoreConfig, which I assume can be used to initialize the state, I'm at a loss. What I don't want is that all my state in the store is initialized with undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify default value for `state` argument and return the same state if no action matches. Try to change your reducer to the following:

```
export function searchTextReducer(state: string = '', action: UpdateSearchTextAction) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case UPDATE:
        return action.text;
      default:
        return state;
    }
};
```